# Access an object thorugh the variable name instead of numeric OID using net-snmp

Tags: snmp, net-snmp

I can ask to a snmp agent the query:

```
snmpwalk -v2c -c public 192.168.56.70 1.3.6.1.2.1.31.1.1.1.1.1
```

I recieve "lo" (loopback interface) as the answer. My question is: How I can access that OID through the names instead of using the OID numbers? That should be as follows:

```
snmpwalk -v2c -c public 192.168.56.70 iso.identified-organization.dod.internet.mgmt.mib-2.ifMIB.ifMIBObjects.ifXTable.ifXEntry.ifName
```

If I send this last query to the snmp agent, i get "Unknown Object Identification". Which changes should I do in the snmp agent configuration to get the same answer as when I am asking through the OID?

Any help will be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: I think this is off-topic since it does not concern programming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally I'd use the simple symbolic name e.g.

```
snmptranslate -M+. -m +ALL   1.3.6.1.2.1.31.1.1.1.1.1     
IF-MIB::ifName.1
```

From the agent's perspective the next two are the same,  i.e. the netsnmp `snmpwalk` utility handles the symbol translations.

```
snmpwalk -v2c -c public 192.168.56.70  1.3.6.1.2.1.31.1.1.1.1.1 
IF-MIB::ifName.1 = STRING: lo
```

Symbol version :

```
snmpwalk -v2c -c public 192.168.56.70   IF-MIB::ifName.1        
IF-MIB::ifName.1 = STRING: lo
```

Include the MIB files if they're not in your default path  `-M+. -m +ALL`

```
snmpwalk -v2c   -c public vvx1   IF-MIB::ifName.1    
IF-MIB::ifName.1 = STRING: lo
```